# Add functions to path - Python

Tags: python, path

I have just started to use Python (I am used to MATLAB).
How should I add a function to path? In matlab you right click on the function and you can add or remove from path.

For instance, a simple program to evaluate the power of a number:
[image]

[image]

As you can see the original program and the function are in the same folder, however the function seems to have an error. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors. Please share your code. Your question also isn't very clear. Did you not run the program to see what the error is?

Answer (score 1):

If you hover the mouse over the redlined identifier, PyCharm will tell you what it thinks is wrong (and give you a balloon to fix it). Alternatively you can press F2 to go to the next error.

In this case it is complaining that you're not following [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) conventions for function and argument names.

> Function names should be lowercase, with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve readability.
>
> Variable names follow the same convention as function names.

From: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names

In addition, you need to import names before you can use them, ie. in app.py:

```
from . import POWER
a = 3
print(POWER.POWER(a))
```

or

```
from .POWER import POWER
a = 3
print(POWER(a))
```

Since you're using PyCharm, you can put your cursor on the name in app.py that is not recognized and press alt+enter and chose the option to "import this name".

Comment: Thanks a lot, you comment was really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Hi function in python define like this :

```
def <funcname>(<arguments>):
    statement....
```

If you want to call function use:

```
<funcname>(<arguments>)
```

your fucntion:

```
def power(num):
    return num**2

print(power(2))
```

output:

```
4
```

but if you want to add it to another .py file

write this code in your app.py

```
from .power import power
print(power(2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Python has a built-in hierarchy of import protocols that I would suggest getting to know. To accomplish what you're trying to do, if you (after cleaning up a bit of syntax, and remove the space between POWER and the brackets, and add a colon to the end of the function definition, ie `def power(Num):`  ) you can access the function from file POWER by adding to the top of app:

```
from POWER import power
```